# How to replace data values in dataframe

Tags: r

I have a little question concerning value replacement in a DF. I know how to replace value using ifelse statement but does exist some function which allows us to don't specify the else condition.

```
df <- data.frame(ID = paste0("ID",1:10),VAL = sample(10,10,replace=T),stringsAsFactors = F)

df$VAL <- ifelse(df$VAL == 1,"*",df$VAL)
```

Thanks

Comment: `df$VAL[df$VAL == 1] <- '*' ` ?

Comment: That's work fine, thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use :

```
 your_val = 1 
 df[df$VAL == your_val,"VAL"] <- "*"
```